# Audio Peripheral Splitting Issue - Mixing 4 and 3 Lines

Tags: audio, speakers, headset, splitter

I have one Headphone jack on my computer.

I want to use one Headset and Speakers on this one jack.

[image: scematic]

I want to use one splitter (yellow) to make two 4 line jacks out of the one 4 line jack on my computer (green).
One Jack I want to use for a headset (blue, top).

On the second 4 line jack, I want to put a splitter (red), that provides me with one separate microphone jack (which will be unused) and one separate audio jack on which I want to connect speakers (blue, right).

Will this work?

I blew two headsets using the wrong splitters (don't mix 3 and 4 line devices on the same 3 or 4 line splitter, kids :) ), so I want to make sure, this works.

Thanks a bunch for any feedback and pardon me, if this is not the exactly best place to ask about this. Please tell me if there's a better place!

Answer (score 0):

'Speaker' outs are reasonably simple to split, assuming each load is approximately equal; if they're not all the volume will go to the lowest impedance. Your computer's op amp won't like pushing full volume to half the expected impedance & you may blow it if you run it hard. At low volume you'd about get away with it. Mics on the other hand don't like splitting at all. Impedances will be totally wrong. I'd forget that part altogether.
The rest you could cobble together with some dedicated plugs, wire & a soldering iron, 20 minute job.

If you want to do this vaguely properly you want an external USB sound card of some sort that is designed for it.

Comment: Sadly having another sound card is no option.

Technically I would only be using one microphone line. Do you thing this setup could lead to a problem?

For Volume I'm not planning on going hard. It's for my working desk only. :)

Comment: Just make up a cable & try it. It's the kind of Heath Robinson job you'll get away with 9 times out of 10. When I was a kid, most of my "hi fi" was built like this.